# High School Trigonometry Problem

Tags: trigonometry

"The famous leaning tower of pisa 'leans' at an angle of 4 degrees, and its top is 56.86 meters above the ground. Determine the height of its top above the ground when it was originally built (standing at right angles to the ground."

Using a quickly drawn illustration, I came to the answer that the original height was also 55.86, however, this seems wrong in my eyes, as the leaning tower's height from the ground is then the same length.

I hope someone can point out where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the original height would've been greater than the vertical height after slanting.

Draw a right angled triangle. The length of tower measured along its side (which is its original height) is the hypotenuse $H$. The lean angle is to the vertical (it would be absurd to think it leans $4$ degrees to the horizontal). That means you have the relationship $\cos 4^{\circ} = \frac{56.86}{H}$ from which you quickly get $H = 56.9988$ metres.

Excuse the crappy diagram.

[image]